# Value from userDefaults not populating URL query string

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am making this chat app with works with a .php file on my webserver to store the data in a SQL db

Here is my code so far:

```
#import "vtchatViewController.h"

@interface vtchatViewController ()

@end

@implementation vtchatViewController

@synthesize messageBox, messageView, Send, Refresh;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *usrName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"user_name"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.com/ios/messages.php"];  [messageView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

}

- (IBAction)refreshButton:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.com/ios/messages.php"];  [messageView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

}

- (IBAction)sendButton:(id)sender {
    // server.com/ios/add.php?user=Username here&message=Message Her

    [messageBox resignFirstResponder];
    NSString* urlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server.com/ios/add.php?user=",usrName "&message=%@", messageBox.text] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding : NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *add = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];



    [messageView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:add]];
    messageBox.Text = @"";


}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

However on the line "viewDidLoad" I can't get it to use the username from my settings bundle:

```
NSString* urlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server.com/ios/add.php?user=",usrName "&message=%@", messageBox.text] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding : NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *add = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

I get the error "Use of undeclared indentifier 'usrName' and also I have no idea if I did implent the "usrName" correct for use in this

I simply need it to send data to "server.com/ios/add.php?" where data should be in this format: "user=Username here&message=Message here"

I got it working if I just use a fixed username, but as said, I have no idea how to make the thing use the username stored in my settings file

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use string format tokens to get it to insert the username into the `urlString` variable like this:

```
NSString* urlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server.com/ios/add.php?user=%@&message=%@", usrName, messageBox.text];
```

That should help you understand why your format string wasn't working and why you were getting that error. My code above isn't escaping the values of `usrName` or `messageBox.text` so you'll need to add those back into your code.

Answer (score 0):

you should let you usrName beacome like a interface variable.

like that:

```
@interface vtchatViewController () {
    NSString *usrName;
}

@end

@implementation vtchatViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    NSString *usrName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"user_name"];
    ...
}

@end
```